# Python - IF for a column in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to turn `NaN` values in the column `GP` in the dataframe `draft` (which has 22 rows) into `0`. I tried these lines but they don't work

```
import pandas as pd
draft =  pd.read_csv('Draft year.csv')

if draft['GP'].isnull():
    draft['GP'] = 0
```

In R there is `ifelse` which does the job nicely but I dont know equivalent in python. Really appreciate any help

Comment: You could use [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension and replace the `NaN`s with zeros.

```
draft['GP'] = [0 if np.isnan(x) else x for x in draft.GP]
```

Answer (score 5):

The .fillna function works for this, you can specify the 'draft' series first if u only want to fillna with 0 for that column. Example below:

```
import pandas as pd

print data3
data3 = pd.read_csv("data2.csv")
data3["Name"].fillna(0, inplace = True)
data3

  Name Name2  Time
0  NaN   NaN     1
1  NaN   NaN     2
2   G     G      3

  Name Name2  Time
0    0   NaN     1
1    0   NaN     2
2   G     G      3
```